Can you use wall switches and fan speed regulator in conjunction with a ceiling fan remote or do you have to choose between the two control options?
I removed an old ceiling fan with a light, wired to 2 3-way switches and a dimmer for the fan speed...so 4 wires in the ceiling box-black, red, white, green. The new fan has only 3 wires - red, white, green. It has a light and a remote. The fan uses a receiver box (pre-wired to the fan) which has red, white, and green wires to attach to. How do I wire a 3 wire fan set up for a remote to a 4 wire box connecting back to the original switches and fan speed dimmer? I want to use both the switches and the remote.

How many wires does the receiver box have going to the fan?

Get another fan.  The new fan has one power wire, a neutral and ground.  The ceiling has two switch hots with neutral and ground.  You could cap one of the switch hots(black or red) and use the other for power to fan.  I am guessing the one for the lights.

The fan you purchased is not compatible with your home wiring as you want to use it.
The home wiring can be used with the fan if either the black or red wire is  capped and not used. This will not allow you to use all the wall switches. The fan and light will work using the remote.
The wiring in the fan should not be modified for safety reasons and could void insurance coverage in the event of a fire.
You need to make a choice to either use the fan with the remote or purchase a fan compatible with your current home wiring.

+1.  You could buy another remote if the fan supports pairing one.  Dipswitches maybe?  Probably the objective is to have one by the door and one by the bed (or wherever), and not some nostalgic attachment to the wall switches?

@jay613   Wall switches are usually more dependable than remotes.  Quite a few companies make the switches that will work.  Fans with remotes only, can be discontinued.  Finding a remote that works after can be difficult.

I've purchased universal remotes for a number of fans, ( usually when a tenant moves and takes the remote or looses it)  They always work well, sometimes better than the ones supplied with the fan.
